# Is there a way to make a websocket reachable through a SRV DNS record?

Tags: websocket, dns, srv-record

I swear I googled this. I was wondering if there is any way to connect to a WebSocket service by resolving a `SRV` DNS query. In principle, this sounds reasonable to me, e.g., in a situation where the port where the service is going to be listening depends on the host and there is not a fixed port.

For example:
Server A listens with a WebSocket on port 1234.
Server B listens with a WebSocket on port 1235.

Server NS assigns a `CNAME` to A, and a `CNAME` to B. It also adds a `SRV` entry that points to A's and B's `CNAME`s, and also points to each port.

When connecting, an user should then connect to something like `srvws://websockethost` rather than `ws://aorbcname:aorbport`.

Is it even possible to do such a thing? Is there any planning at all about this? Is there any alternative to solve this kind of problem, where I need to communicate ports along with the DNS query?

**Update:** looking around I found this draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ibc-websocket-dns-srv-02

But I am not really sure how to interpret this. Is this a standard? Was this even approved? Is this just a proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RFC 2782 [A DNS RR for specifying the location of services (DNS SRV)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) it states

> Currently, one must either know the exact address of a server to
> contact it, or broadcast a question.

> The SRV RR allows administrators to use several servers for a single
> domain, to move services from host to host with little fuss, and to
> designate some hosts as primary servers for a service and others as
> backups.

The format of a SRV RR is

> _Service._Proto.Name TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target

There is no technical reason that you couldn't use a SRV record to point to a WS. As you point out it has been the subject of an IETF draft. That doesn't appear to have gone any further, though the reasons aren't clear from its [history](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ibc-websocket-dns-srv/history/) it does appear to have been merged with RFC 6455 [The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) There is a [discussion](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg06968.html) concerning the inclusion of IETF draft [DNS SRV Resource Records for the WebSocket Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ibc-websocket-dns-srv-02) that has the following

> SRV would be a perfect choice for many people
> [...] It would be fully optional from the admin and user
> perspective. The website owner could decide to use SRV or not. The
> only requeriment, of course, os that WS clients support it

So while there is no technical specification, there is certainly no reason why you can't / shouldn't. The idea has been proposed and allowed to die because ultimately it is up to you if you want to use a SRV record to find a WS service that is perfectly within protocol.

And in my opinion, it would solve a number of problems.

**Edited to add**

After some more digging around on the IETF message boards. (curiosity as to why it wasn't implemented got the better of me) I found [this message](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg08011.html) from the guy who proposed it

> I was proposing it, but after long discussions in the maillist I've
> understood that mandating DNS SRV in WS clients would break too much
> assumptions in HTTP world (which commonly just sees above HTTP layer
> and not below).

> The existence of HTTP proxies is also a big handicap since those
> proxies should be upgraded/modified in order to perform DNS SRV
> resolution *just* in case the HTTP request is a WebSocket handshake.
> This last argument is enough to not mandate SRV resolution.

So while it sounds a good idea, the people who really understand this stuff (and write the standards for it) found some issues that suggested simply using standard HTTP / A record look ups.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However, it is unclear to me what do you mean by "there is no reason why you can't". I mean, of course I could be able to do such a thing with a proprietary client, but is there any way to do it in a web browser? I guess I should do the dns resolution step on my own, and that isn't allowed by browsers, am I right? Would there be other reasonable solutions of this kind?

Comment: @MatteoMonti I wrote this off the back of the DNS tag, from a DNS angle I can tell you what it does, why it does it and probably find the original discussion about the reasons for doing it. When it comes to implementing, I usually stumble around and pass it along to people who actually understand that stuff - You are probably best posting another, more explicit question about how to look up a WS service to whatever technology you are using clientside. (or add the tag to this one)